# Unable to import one springboot application into another

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to import project 'DatabaseService' into another project 'GetUsersFunction' in IntelliJ.
[image]
Although I have mentioned the dependency in the pom.xml file of 'GetUsersFunction' still, I am unable to build the project.

pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>DatabaseService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here. The complete code can be found here - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/AWSLamnda

Comment: have you defined the module in the main pom?

Comment: yes I have defined both the modules in the main pom.

Answer (score 0):

According to this guide (https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-how-to-create-a-multi-module-project/) you need the following:

*pom.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <!-- parent pom -->
    <groupId>com.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserPlanning</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <version>1.0</version>

        <!-- sub modules -->
        <modules>
        <module>DatabaseService</module>
        <module>GetUserFunctionns</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

your *DatabaseService/pom.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <!-- parent pom -->
    <parent>
        <artifactId>UserPlanning</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.session</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>DatabaseService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

your *GetUserFunctions/pom.xml*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <!-- parent pom -->
    <parent>
        <artifactId>UserPlanning</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.session</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>GetUserFunctionns</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>DatabaseService</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I believe that should do the trick